# Finding the median of the merged array of two sorted arrays in O(logN)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, median

Refering to the solution present at [MIT handout](http://www2.myoops.org/course_material/mit/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/30C68118-E436-4FE3-8C79-6BAFBB07D935/0/ps9sol.pdf)

I have tried to figure out the solution myself but have got stuck and I believe I need help to understand the following points.

1. In the function header used in the solution

   MEDIAN -SEARCH (A[1 . . l], B[1 . . m], max(1,n/2 − m), min(l, n/2))

I do not understand the last two arguments why not simply 1, l why the max and min respectively.

1. In the pseduo code

   if left > right

   why do we switch A and B arrays if we reach the above condition.

Thanking You.

Comment: @user2357112 has provided great explanation. But my data structures and algorithms are not upto the mark. It would be great if someone can elaborate on how elements are eliminated. Specifically, quoting from below "We can tell in advance that if a number is at a position less than..."

Comment: if left > right, doesn't need more explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when

```
left > right
```

then, it means median is not present in A. So, it must be present in B. Thus we switch.

For instance, try to work out the algorithm for

```
A = [ 1, 5] and B = [2, 3, 4].
```

Now, answer is 3. 
Initially (left, right) is (1, 3). Then it becomes (1, 1) and then (2, 1) now, we switch A and B and continue the procedure on B to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
MEDIAN-SEARCH(A[1..l], B[1..m], max(1, ceil(n/2)-m), min(l, ceil(n/2)))
```

the `max` and `min` calls restrict the region of `A` we're searching. We can tell in advance that if a number is at a position less than `ceil(n/2)-m` in `A`, then too many elements of `A` are greater than it for it to be the median. Similarly, a number at a position past `ceil(n/2)` is greater than too many elements of `A` to be the median.

If `left > right`, then the binary search has reduced the segment of `A` we're searching down to nothing. Switching `A` and `B` means we start searching the other array.

Comment: But how does the algorithm terminate if we keep switching. For example say, left and right refer to array A, now if this interval shortens and finally the "if" condition is met, we switch the Arrays and restart with a new interval. How would the algorithm terminate ?

Comment: @hershey92: We can only switch once. If we don't find the median in one array, it has to be in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in JAVA using recursion which has log(m+n) time complexity.

```
package FindMedianBetween2SortedArraysOfUnequalLength;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UsingKthSmallestElementLogic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the first SORTED array");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] array1 = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the first SORTED array");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            array1[i]=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the second SORTED array");
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int[] array2 = new int[m];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the second SORTED array");
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            array2[i]=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Median of the two SORTED arrays is: "+findMedian(array1,array2,array1.length,array2.length));
    }
    finally{
        in.close();
    }
}
private static int findMedian(int[] a, int[] b,
        int aLength, int bLength) { 

    int left = (aLength+bLength+1)>>1;
    int right = (aLength+bLength+2)>>1;
    return ((findKthSmallestElement(a,b,a.length,b.length,left)+findKthSmallestElement(a,b,a.length,b.length,right))/2);
}
private static int findKthSmallestElement(int[] a, int[] b,
        int aLength, int bLength, int k) {                    // All the 5 parameters passed are VERY VERY IMP

    /* to maintain uniformity, we will assume that size_a is smaller than size_b
    else we will swap array in call :) */
    if(aLength>bLength)
        return findKthSmallestElement(b, a, bLength, aLength, k);

    /* We have TWO BASE CASES
     * Now case when size of smaller array is 0 i.e there is no elemt in one array*/
    //BASE CASE 1. If the smallest array length is 0
    if(aLength == 0 && bLength > 0)
            return b[k-1]; // due to zero based index

    /* case where k==1 that means we have hit limit */
    //BASE CASE 2. If k==1
    if(k==1)
            return Math.min(a[0], b[0]);

    /* Now the divide and conquer part */
    int i =  Math.min(aLength, k/2) ; // k should be less than the size of array  
    int j =  Math.min(bLength, k/2) ; // k should be less than the size of array  

    if(a[i-1] > b[j-1])
            // Now we need to find only K-j th element
            return findKthSmallestElement(a, Arrays.copyOfRange(b, j, b.length), a.length, b.length -j, k-j);
    else
            return findKthSmallestElement(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, i, a.length), b, a.length-i, b.length,  k-i);
}
}
/*
Analysis:
    Time Complexity = O(log(n+m))
    Space Complexity = O(1)*/
```