# Find the median of two sorted arrays of different size in O(min(log(n),log(m)) complexity

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, median, sorting

Before replying, please beware that both arrays are of different size and the requested complexity is  O(min(log(n),log(m)), this question was never asked on stackoverflow.

I've been trying to modify a O(log(n+m)) solution to work but couldn't, the following solution searches for the kth (median of merged array) element, but the complexity is log(n+m).

In order to solve it in O(min(log(n),log(m))), we need to cut k/2 of the second array members as well on every recursion call.

Updated code:

```
int select(int *a, int *b, int sa, int sb, int k) {
    int ma = sa < k/2 ? sa - 1 : k/2 - 1;
    int mb = k - ma - 2;
    if (sa + sb < k)
        return -1;
    if (sa == 0)
        return b[k - 1];
    if (sb == 0)
        return a[k - 1];
    if (k == 1)
        return a[0] < b[0] ? a[0] : b[0];
    if (a[ma] == b[mb])
        return a[ma];
    if (a[ma] < b[mb])
        return select(a + ma + 1, b, sa - ma - 1, mb + 1, k - ma - 1);
    return select(a, b + mb + 1, ma + 1, sb - mb - 1, k - mb - 1);
}

/*
median:
uses select to find the median of the union of a and b (where a and b are sorted
positive integer arrays of sizes sa and sb respectively).
*/
int median(int *a, int *b, int sa, int sb) {
    int m1, m2;
    if ((sa + sb) % 2 == 1)
        return select(a, b, sa, sb, (sa + sb)/2 + 1);
    return select(a, b, sa, sb, (sa + sb)/2);

}

int main() {
    int a[3] = {2, 4, 6};
    int b[11] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31};
    printf("\n median is %d\n", median(a, b, 3, 11));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to prove the time complexity and corectness of the algorithm with no luck.

Comment: Compare the middle elements of both. What does that tell you?

Comment: Sadly, nothing. after 6hours straight. what do you mean? middle elements of both are both the medians of each array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have two arrays `A` and `B`, of sizes `m`, and `n` respectively, with `m <= n`.

Then we have the following:

---

Lemma: The median of `A` and `B` is the same as the median of `A` and `B'`, where `B'` is the middle `m` or `m + 1` elements of `B`, depending on whether `m` and `n` have the same parity or not.

---

Now it only remains to use your `O(log(m + n))` algorithm to find the median of `A` and `B'`.

Proof of the lemma: almost obvious ...

Comment: I asked for a o(min(log(n),log(m)) solution.

Comment: This IS an `O(min(log(n), log(m)))` solution. The array `B'` has `O(m)` length.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing the almost ovious solution here. when it comes down to implementation.. I tried calling the median(A + midA,sizeA - midA ,B, sizeB/2+1) where A[mid]<B[mid]. it is not that simple as you think.

Comment: @DecoderM It isn't about the size of the median.  It is about the size of the array.  You need to replace the longer array with just a section around its midpoint.

Comment: Could you please help me proving the lemma? It may be obvious but I'm struggeling.

Comment: @DecoderM Suppose that `n - m >= 2`. Then the smallest element of `B` must be inferior or equal to the median. Similarly, the largest element of `B` must be be superior or equal to the median. Hence removing both of them from the array `B` does not change the median. This procedure can be repeated until `n - m = 0 or 1`.

Comment: @MikeMB Of course I'm sure this works, because I have given a proof above. If you don't believe, please give a counter example.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Seems I havn't read you algorithm carefully enough.

Comment: @WhatsUp, thanks for clarifying this. I'm not sure the code I attached indeed runs in O(min(log(n), log(m))), as I'm using select to find the kth member (median here), will you be able to help with this? Thanks!

Comment: @DecoderM It seems not. Your code `select` runs in linear time. You should use something else, which can be found, for example, in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176431/finding-the-median-of-the-merged-array-of-two-sorted-arrays-in-ologn?rq=1

Comment: linear time? it's log(m+n) at most. as explained here: www.malloc.co/algorithms/finding-the-median-of-two-sorted-arrays/

Comment: @DecoderM Sorry, you are right. I misread the code. So a priori the code in your post is `O(log(m + n))`.